# Recovering multiple errors in Javacc

Tags: javacc

Is there a way in javacc to parse an input file further even after detecting an error. I got to know that there are several ways such as panic mode recovery, phrase level recovery and so on. But I can't figure how to implement it in javacc jjt file.
For an example assume my input file is

```
Line 1: int i
Line 2: int x; 
Line 3: int k
```

So what I want is after detecting the error of missing semicolon at line 1, proceed parsing and find the error at line 3 too.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the way of panic mode error recovery,but it too have some bugs. What I did was I edit my grammar so that once I encounter a missing character in a line of the input file(in the above case a semicolon) parser proceed until it finds a similar character. Those similar characters are called synchronizing tokens.

See the example below.
First I replaced all the SEMICOLON tokens in my grammar with this.

```
    Semicolon()
```

Then add this new production rule.

```
    void Semicolon() :
    {}
    {
    try 
    {
    <SEMICOLON> 
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Token t;
        System.out.println(e.toString());
         do {
       t = getNextToken();
         } while (t.kind != SEMICOLON && t!=null && t.kind != EOF );
    }
    }
```

Once I encounter a missing character parser search for a similar character.When it finds such character it returns to the rule which called it.

Example:-
Assume a semicolon missing in a variable declaration.

```
    int a=10 <--- no semicolon
```

So parser search for a semicolon.At some point it finds a semicolon.

```
    ___(some code)__; method(param1);
```

So after finding the first semicolon in the above example it returns to the variable declaration rule(because it is the one which called the semicolon() method.) But what we find after the newly find semicolon is a function call,not a variable declaration.

Can anyone please suggest a way to solve this problem.